Why is the line border colour of a portion of a Plotly Go pie slice two seperate colours?
I am trying to create a pie chart using Plotly.Go and place it into a Streamlit app. My pie chart is basically complete, and just requires a border colour around each differing slice. I was able to add a border colour to each slice using the marker(line) function but have ran into an issue where one of my slices contains a different colour on the left hand side compared to the rest.
I currently have the following code block which shows how I've created the pie chart:
labels = [f"{total_servicecount[key]} {key.capitalize()}" for key in total_servicecount.keys()]
values = list(total_servicecount.values())

service_colours = {
    'ok': '#173928',
    'warning': '#3E3B16',
    'critical': '#502428',
    'unknown': '#262730',
    'pending': '#28b7e2' 
}

service_colours_bg = {
    'ok': '#35e916',
    'warning': '#FFA500',
    'critical': '#FF0000',
    'unknown': '#808080',
    'pending': '#28b7e2' 
}

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(
    labels=labels,
    values=values,
    hole=0.7,
    marker=dict(
        colors=list(service_colours.values()),
        line=dict(
            color=list(service_colours_bg.values()),
            width=2
        ),
        pattern=dict(
            bgcolor=list(service_colours_bg.values())
        )
    ),
    pull=[0.01] * len(values),
    hoverinfo='label+percent',
    textinfo='none',
    hovertemplate="<b>%{label}</b><br>Count: %{value}<br>Percentage: %{percent}<extra></extra>",
    domain=dict(x=[0, 1], y=[0, 1]),
    opacity=1                      
)])

fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    height=200,
    width=190,
    margin=dict(l=0, r=5, t=5, b=5),
    legend=dict(
        orientation='h',
        xanchor='center',
        yanchor='bottom',
        x=0.2,
        y=-0.4
    ),
    annotations=[dict(text='<b>Service<br>Status</b>', x=0.5, y=0.5, font_size=18, showarrow=False)]
)

st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=False)

And here is an image of my pie chart:
Current pie chart showing incorrect border colour on left side of 'warning' slice.
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Can you provide data to be reproduced? Data will make it easier to get an answer. And is it the same event when executed plotly alone?

@r-beginners here is the data: Labels: ['321 Ok', '6 Warning', '0 Critical', '0 Unknown', '0 Pending'], Values: [321, 6, 0, 0, 0]. And yes I get the same result executing plotly alone.

They simply overlap due to the small size of the data. I changed the value to this. I also changed the cutout for clarity.values = [321, 16, 10, 10, 10] and pull = [0.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], get graph

@r-beginners So how would I work around this, as 'values' is live data that is constantly changing?

The only thing that comes to mind right now is to reorder the data as large, small, large, small.
